# Hidden File Extensions in .htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I have hidden my file extensions on my website URL and I am wondering if I need to change my links on the other pages.

For example, If I have 'www.example.com/packages', should I then change the links pointing to that page from href="packages.php" to href="packages" since the file extension is now just 'packages' instead of 'packages.php'.

Is this important to change or would it be better to leave it as-is? Which would be better for SEO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to have links as `href="packages"` for SEO purpose.

And for the URLs already indexed in search engines use this 301 rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would whitelist it.

`RewriteRule ^/(products|about_page|other)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ /$1.php?param=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/(products|about_page|other)/?$ /$1.php [L]`

This way, you control which files are accessible without the extension (and can even fake a REST router with parameters).

But to answer your question: Yes. If you're going to implement a feature, you should use it.